# ORA-00932: inconsistent dadatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I got a simple(but big) insert command that's giving me this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent dadatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

Here's the insert:

```
INSERT INTO TB_SOLIC_COTACAO
(   NUM_SOLIC , 
    NUM_HIST_SOLIC , 
    COD_FILIAL , 
    COD_CORRETOR , 
    COD_ACCOUNT , 
    NUM_CGC_PROPON , 
    COD_RAMO , 
    COD_PRODUTO , 
    TIP_RAMO , 
    TIP_ENVIO , 
    COD_STATUS , 
    NUM_APOLICE_EMITIDA , 
    DT_EMISSAO , 
    DSC_LOCAL_ASSINAT , 
    DT_LOCAL_ASSINAT , 
    DT_ATUALIZ , 
    ID_USUARIO_ATUALIZ , 
    COD_MOTIVO_RECUSA , 
    DSC_COMPLEMENTO_MOTIVO_RECUSA, 
    NUM_PROPOSTA , 
    TIP_MOE_SOLIC , 
    VAL_LIMITE_APOLICE , 
    VAL_PMO_ESTIMADO , 
    COD_SUBSCRITOR , 
    DSC_EMAIL , 
    COD_SUB_LOCAL , 
    IND_RMO_CLAUSULA , 
    IND_VERIF_CRIVO , 
    TIP_SEGURO , 
    IND_BLOQUEIO_CORRETOR , 
    COD_ASSESSORIA , 
    DSC_EMAIL_ASSESSORIA , 
    DT_EMAIL_AVISO_COBRANCA , 
    IND_EXCLUSIVIDADE , 
    DT_EXCLUSIVIDADE , 
    COD_TIPO_USUARIO , 
    TIP_ENDOS , 
    TIP_MODAL_EMIS , 
    DSC_OBS_PARECER , 
    DSC_OBS_COTACAO
   )
     ( SELECT num_solic ,
              2 ,
              cod_filial ,
              cod_corretor ,
              cod_account ,
              num_cgc_propon ,
              cod_ramo ,
              cod_produto ,
              tip_ramo ,
              tip_envio ,
              3 ,
              num_apolice_emitida ,
              dt_emissao ,
              dsc_local_assinat ,
              dt_local_assinat ,
              SYSDATE ,
              17590 ,
              ' ' ,
              cod_motivo_recusa ,
              dsc_complemento_motivo_recusa ,
              num_proposta ,
              tip_moe_solic ,
              val_limite_apolice ,
              val_pmo_estimado ,
              cod_subscritor ,
              dsc_email ,
              cod_sub_local ,
              ind_rmo_clausula ,
              ind_verif_crivo ,
              tip_seguro ,
              ind_bloqueio_corretor ,
              cod_assessoria ,
              dsc_email_assessoria ,
              dt_email_aviso_cobranca ,
              ind_exclusividade ,
              dt_exclusividade ,
              cod_tipo_usuario,
              tip_endos,
              tip_modal_emis
              dsc_obs_parecer,
              dsc_obs_cotacao 
       FROM tb_solic_cotacao 
         WHERE num_solic = 93
                 AND num_hist_solic = 1 );
```

I know what this error means, I already checked row by row of the insert but the datatypes seem ok to me! Really don't know what's wrong.

Here's de definition of the table:

```
NUM_SOLIC                     NOT NULL NUMBER(18)          
NUM_HIST_SOLIC                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)          
COD_FILIAL                             VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)    
COD_CORRETOR                           VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)   
COD_ACCOUNT                            VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)   
NUM_CGC_PROPON                NOT NULL NUMBER(18)          
COD_RAMO                      NOT NULL NUMBER(5)           
COD_PRODUTO                   NOT NULL NUMBER(5)           
TIP_RAMO                      NOT NULL CHAR(3 CHAR)        
TIP_ENVIO                     NOT NULL CHAR(1 CHAR)        
COD_STATUS                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)           
NUM_APOLICE_EMITIDA                    VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)   
DT_EMISSAO                             DATE                
DSC_LOCAL_ASSINAT                      VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)   
DT_LOCAL_ASSINAT                       DATE                
DT_ATUALIZ                    NOT NULL DATE                
ID_USUARIO_ATUALIZ                     VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)   
COD_MOTIVO_RECUSA                      NUMBER(5)           
DSC_COMPLEMENTO_MOTIVO_RECUSA          VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)  
NUM_PROPOSTA                           VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)   
TIP_MOE_SOLIC                          CHAR(1 CHAR)        
VAL_LIMITE_APOLICE                     FLOAT(126)          
VAL_PMO_ESTIMADO                       FLOAT(126)          
COD_SUBSCRITOR                         VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)   
DSC_EMAIL                              VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) 
COD_SUB_LOCAL                          VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)    
IND_RMO_CLAUSULA                       NUMBER(1)           
IND_VERIF_CRIVO                        NUMBER(1)           
TIP_SEGURO                             CHAR(3 CHAR)        
IND_BLOQUEIO_CORRETOR                  CHAR(1 CHAR)        
COD_ASSESSORIA                         NUMBER(10)          
DSC_EMAIL_ASSESSORIA                   VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) 
DT_EMAIL_AVISO_COBRANCA                DATE                
IND_EXCLUSIVIDADE                      CHAR(1 CHAR)        
DT_EXCLUSIVIDADE                       DATE                
COD_TIPO_USUARIO                       NUMBER(5)           
TIP_ENDOS                              VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)   
TIP_MODAL_EMIS                         VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)   
DSC_OBS_PARECER                        CLOB                
DSC_OBS_COTACAO                        CLOB
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: You have 3 values here: `SYSDATE, 17590, ' ' ,` for 2 columns in the column list (the `17590` seems to be out of place there). And a missing comma below, at: `tip_modal_emis`

Comment: A good editor with a column copy-paste mode is very useful for these long sql insert statements. You can copy your list of target columns and paste it to the right or left of your select or values clause to make it more easy to ensure you have the right mapping. Aligning all of your commas in a single column also helps highlight any that are missing.

Comment: Hey @ypercube, I really missed that comma. Answer the question so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether:

- the number of columns match in the listing of column names and values
- in each row and column you have a pair

The easiest way to achieve this would be an excel table where you paste into the first row the columns (with their type) in each cell and on lower rows you paste the values you want to insert. Find the problems and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the easiest way is:

```
  DROP TABLE TB_SOLIC_COTACAO;

  Create TABLE TB_SOLIC_COTACAO as
  (SELECT num_solic ,
          2 as NUM_HIST_SOLIC,
          cod_filial ,
          cod_corretor ,
          cod_account ,
          num_cgc_propon ,
          cod_ramo ,
          cod_produto ,
          tip_ramo ,
          tip_envio ,
          3 as COD_STATUS,
          num_apolice_emitida ,
          dt_emissao ,
          dsc_local_assinat ,
          dt_local_assinat ,
          SYSDATE ,
          17590 as DT_ATUALIZ,
          ' ' as ID_USUARIO_ATUALIZ,
          cod_motivo_recusa ,
          dsc_complemento_motivo_recusa ,
          num_proposta ,
          tip_moe_solic ,
          val_limite_apolice ,
          val_pmo_estimado ,
          cod_subscritor ,
          dsc_email ,
          cod_sub_local ,
          ind_rmo_clausula ,
          ind_verif_crivo ,
          tip_seguro ,
          ind_bloqueio_corretor ,
          cod_assessoria ,
          dsc_email_assessoria ,
          dt_email_aviso_cobranca ,
          ind_exclusividade ,
          dt_exclusividade ,
          cod_tipo_usuario,
          tip_endos,
          tip_modal_emis
          dsc_obs_parecer,
          dsc_obs_cotacao 
   FROM tb_solic_cotacao 
     WHERE num_solic = 93
             AND num_hist_solic = 1)
```